# Is it possible to validate a FormRequest without dependency injection?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using a `FormRequest` to validate a delete request, but I do not need to access the request inside of my controller. I just need it for validation.

I find the unused variable annoying, but I can't see anything in [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#creating-form-requests) that suggests I can call anything on the class to validate it.

Form request:

```
class DeleteList extends FormRequest
{
    protected $errorBag = 'delete_list';

    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'confirm' => 'required|accepted'
        ];
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public function postDelete(DeleteList $request, ListService $listService, $site, $list)
{
    $listService->delete($site, $list);
    return redirect()->route('site.lists', ['site' => $site]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
public function postDelete(ListService $listService, $site, $list)
{
    $this->validate(request(), ['confirm'=>'required|accepted']);

    $listService->delete($site, $list);
    return redirect()->route('site.lists', ['site' => $site]);
}
```

But personally I like your solution better, even if it means having an unused variable.

Comment: The reason I stayed away from validating inside of the controller is so that I can replicate the validation rules if I need to, it's just annoying that it is unused!